# Mean age of people

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I have the following datas:
[image: fg]
I want to find mean age by using following formula,
[image: f]

Any way to do this in general in Mathematica easily.

Comment: I was under the impression that SE can handle Latex(?) directly, why use a (blurry for me) image?

Comment: I turned mean at around five and a half. So that's one data point.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need `EmpiricalDistribution`:

```
data = {14, 15, 16, 22, 24, 25};
weights = {1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 5};

\[ScriptCapitalD] = EmpiricalDistribution[weights -> data];

Expectation[x, x \[Distributed] \[ScriptCapitalD]]
(* 21 *)
```

Comment: To the downvoter, I am interested in what's wrong with my answer, would you please elaborate. I'm not trying to complain here, I just want to improve my answer if possible.

Answer (score 10):

```
values = {14, 15, 16, 22, 24, 25};
weights = {1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 5};
```

You can also use [`WeightedData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WeightedData.html):

```
Mean @ WeightedData[values, weights]
```

> ```
> 21
> ```

or use `Mean` with `EmpiricalDistribution`:

```
Mean @ EmpiricalDistribution[weights -> values]
```

> ```
> 21
> ```

Both methods also work with symbolic input:

```
values = Array[Subscript[x, #] &, 5];
weights = Array[Subscript[w, #] &, 5];

Mean @ WeightedData[values, weights]
```

[image]

```
TeXForm @ %
```

> $$\frac{w_1 x_1+w_2 x_2+w_3 x_3+w_4 x_4+w_5 x_5}{w_1+w_2+w_3+w_4+w_5}$$

```
Mean @ EmpiricalDistribution[weights -> values] // Together // TeXForm
```

> $$\frac{w_1 x_1+w_2 x_2+w_3 x_3+w_4 x_4+w_5 x_5}{w_1+w_2+w_3+w_4+w_5}$$

Answer (score 5):

These are all quite fancy solutions so far. For beginners' sake, I'd like to add a somewhat more elementary one that uses somewhat more universal tools:

```
ages = {14, 15, 16, 22, 24, 25};
counts = {1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 5};

ages.counts/Total[counts]
```

> 21

The `.` (a.k.a. `Dot`) computes this sum

```
Sum[ages[[i]] counts[[i]], {i, 1, Length[ages]}]
```

and `Total` computes this one:

```
Sum[counts[[i]], {i, 1, Length[ages]}]
```

So one can also obtain the result as follows:

```
Sum[ages[[i]] counts[[i]], {i, 1, Length[ages]}]/Sum[counts[[i]], {i, 1, Length[counts]}]
```

But `Dot` and `Total` are typically faster because they rely on very optimized libraries in the background. And of course, it is also shorter to type.

Answer (score 3):

Using your formula

```
Clear["Global`*"]

ages = {14, 15, 16, 22, 24, 25};

counts = {1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 5};

Evaluate[n /@ ages] = counts;

?n
```

[image]

```
mean = Sum[j*n[j], {j, ages}]/Total[counts]

(* 21 *)
```